# PhoneGap app: Invalid .apk file: manifest is missing target sdk version

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I build my PhoneGap app on [PhoneGap Build](http://build.phonegap.com), then download the APK and I use [Diawi](https://www.diawi.com/) for install it on an Android smartphone. When I click Send on Diawi I get this error:

```
An error occurred: 4001606: Invalid .apk file: manifest is missing target SDK version
```

Notice: The build log from PhoneGap Build says `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`

So I tried to install the APK file directly on the smartphone and the installation is ok but some functionality (ie. recording audio) does not work.

Some helps?

Answer (score 1):

> **Please add versionCode and versionName in your build.gradle**
>
> android {
>
> defaultConfig {
>
> ```
>    -----
>    minSdkVersion 19
>    targetSdkVersion 29
>    versionCode 1
>    versionName "1.0"
> ```
>
> }
>   }

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue by putting the value of **versionCode** != 0. like  versionCode 1.
and good lyck